# What's the deal with the library off the clock tower?

Tags: fez

Off the clock tower there's a screen with a big official-looking building. When you go inside there's a smallish room with some pictures on the wall, a bookshelf, and a fireplace.

I've tried pressing up in front of the fireplace, but nothing happens. According to the map there's a secret in this room, but for the life of me I don't see any clues there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Press** <kbd>X</kbd> **next to the bookshelf—it's a false door.**

[image: bookshelf's reveal]

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't seeing any hint in the room, but now that I look at your screenshot I see a photo of the opened bookshelf.

Comment: How did you find that? Did you try pressing all the keys in front of every wall of the room?

Comment: @wil: As Tony said, look at the photos on the walls.

Comment: I noticed a changed in the music when I was in front in the door, so I think there were multiple cues.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>X</kbd> in front of the bookshelf and rotate. I went right by it the first time, too.